# AR with Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, arkit, arcore

I am new on this site, and I am writing because I am a bit lost with RA and the different platforms to use.

To sum up, I will have to work on an app with unity, which allows to put 3d models of industrial machines in a real empty factory.

So first I would like to know which is the best framework to do so. During my studies I had to work with Tango, but google stopped the project, and all the documentation seemed to have disappeared. So I have many other choice like vuforia, arcore, arkit and so on.

I think to answer this question, I have to determine how I will proceed to do this job, to place correctly each machine in the real world. Those are the methods I found on the internet:

- place object with GPS coordinate.
- Place object thanks to the image recognition of the empty factory.
- Place the object in the room by touching the screen where we want to put it, and then allow the user to translate the 3D object to place it exactly where he wants.

As I am a student and I am very new in RA, I would appreciate to have some help on the best methode to use, and then, which framework to use.

Thanks!

Antoine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placing an object, which you already have a model of, onto a surface in real world is the introduction example of Augmented Reality.

For indoor, you generally don't want GPS. Having to bring an image into an empty factory to show your object is a bad user experience. What you want is marker-less AR similar to a 3D viewer program, e.g. GLTF viewer app (which I helped write) on Android and iOS, where you allow the user to put a 3d object into a real space.

If you want to use marker-less AR, you can use Unity's built-in AR support which depends on ARKit / ARCore. You can also use a framework that sits on top of ARKit and ARCore that allows you to not having to worry about phones that don't have these libraries.

Using such a framework, you can limit the object scale, and only allow the user to rotate the object while putting it on a surface. This allows the user to try out different placements of their machines in the factory.

Disclosure: I work for and help created such a stack for a company called [8th Wall](https://www.8thwall.com/).

Another option is to not worry about frameworks and use the example program provided by Apple https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/building_your_first_ar_experience and the example program provided by Google https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity/guides/hello-ar-sample . You have to create your application twice but you can learn more about the capabilities of each platform.